# How can I view the list of available games on Poker Stars?

Tags: online

I am in the USA and only have access to PokerStars.net which is for play-money chips. Is there a way for me to view the available list of current cash games on pokerstars.com (the real-money site)? I want to get a feeling for the number/stakes of Stud (high only) at any given time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to download the pokerstars.com client (possibly requiring a proxy) and then browse the games without even having an account.

I am able to do this by right-clicking on the window border of the "Log In" dialog and closing it.

[image]

In case you are not able to do this, here is a screenshot taken at the time of this posting, of the stakes available (only fixed-limit stud is offered):

[image]

$2/$4 with a 0.30 USD ante seems to be the most popular, with one full table, one table with seven players and 17 tables with two players (only two of these tables are actually in play, since there is a player sitting out at most of them).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that I could still get the client software even still being in the US.